# Compare dates From - To

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

It seems impossible to learn how date comparison works.
Php is this, Js is that.

I have a HTML table with dates:

```
2016-02-01 08:16:31
2016-02-01 18:55:52
2016-02-02 15:13:41
...
```

Now i'd like to build a JS to filter dates out.
So, i grab dates with jquery as text, and convert it to a dateobj:

```
$('td.datum').each(  function() {
  //Get this date
  thisDate = new Date( $(this).text() );
...
```

Next i use `bootstrap-datepicker` to choose dates.
I grab selected dates, and convert them to date obj.

```
dateStart = new Date( $('#dateStart').val() );
dateEnd = new Date( $('#dateEnd').val() );
```

Now i made a if statement to sort dates:

```
if (thisDate >= dateStart && thisDate <= dateEnd ) {
  $(this).parent().show();
}
else {
  $(this).parent().hide();
}
```

My problem is now, that if dateStart is `2016-01-01`
and dateEnd is `2016-01-02`
Only `2016-01-01`will be shown.
I'll have to set `dateEnd`to `2016-01-03` to show `2016-01-02`.

Why is that?

I thought `<= dateEnd`in my if statement should involve choosen `dateEnd`?

**UPDATE**

My soloution will be:

```
//Add one day to dateEnd to get time rigth (00:00:00)
dateEnd.setDate(dateEnd.getDate() + 1);
```

I'll add one day to the selected end day.

Comment: Why bother making new dates if you want to sort? YYYY-MM-DD sorts in alphaabetical order just fine

Comment: If you just need to compare them why just not use `.getTime()` method of Date objects and compare integer results?

Comment: @Bearburger How will i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably forgetting about the time component of the date object...

Using the following dates:

```
thisDate = '2016-02-02 15:13:41'
dateStart = '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
dateEnd = '2016-02-02 00:00:00'
```

`thisDate` can never be between `dateStart` and `dateEnd`

```
if (thisDate >= dateStart && thisDate <= dateEnd ) {
  $(this).parent().show();
}
else {
  $(this).parent().hide();
}
```

to fix this, you can:

(1) Pad the end date, so that it really covers the full day...

```
dateEnd = new Date( $('#dateEnd').val() + ' 23:59:59.999' );
```

or

(2) trim out the time part, when you parse the html dates

```
$('td.datum').each(  function() {
  //Get this date
  thisDate = new Date( $(this).text().substring(0, 10) );
```

Comment: Oh, yes. That's true. Thank you. Now how will i solve this in best way?!